# Laravel API Suddenly Returning an Passport 401 Unauthenticated Error

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I have a setup where 2 Laravel 5.3 setups acting as API and client for decoupled e-commerce solution.

after working about a year, suddenly it started to return 401 Unauthenticated error.

My implementation is done exactly according to the Laravel 5.3 doc.

**Error was**
*Client error: "GET" http://myapi.com/api/get/product/ resulted in a "401 Unauthorized" response:{"error":"Unauthenticated."}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observations**

- We found that website frontend was unable to connect to backend to fetch data.
- API was returning and authentication error.
- Further drill down revealed that the it was an issue with authentication token.
- Then we checked the token and found that they were expired.

**Root Cause**

- According to Laravel documentation ([API Authentication (Passport)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#token-lifetimes)) Laravel Version 5.3 tokens do not need to be refreshed and renewed.
- Contradicting to the document Laravel 5.3 tokens expire after 1 Year and need to be refreshed/renewed.
- Ironically the “Laravel Refresh Token” also expire in the same day, making automatic renewal of the Token after the expiration impossible.

**Solution**

- Before generating Laravel 5.3 Token, extend the Refresh Token lifetime to larger value than Access Token.
- Use below code in AuthServiceProvider.php **boot method and below the $this->registerPolicies();**

  $this->registerPolicies();

  Passport::routes();
  Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
- Ignoring the Laravel 5.3 document, implement a Token renew method using Refresh Token.